# Find missing items in a List<T>

Tags: c#, linq

Can someone convert this to C# LINQ for me please ??

```
SELECT *
FROM   vf
       LEFT JOIN dbvf
       ON     vf.sid  =dbvf.sid
       AND    vf.cid  =dbvf.cid
WHERE  dbvf.sid IS NULL
```

Both vf and dbvf are `List<T>`. sid and cid are integers.

What I am trying to do is find items in vf that are missing in dbvf.

Comment: If dbfv.sid is null,why is it even in the join criteria? also, linqpad is your friend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
                  var ret =   from p1 in vf
                              join p2 in dbvf
                              on p1.sid equals p2.sid && p1.cid equals p2.cid into g
                              from p2 in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              where p2 == null
                              select new {vf=p1, dbvf=p2}
```

or this simple

```
vf.Except(dbvf);
```

Comment: after I implemented IEquatable based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx,  vf.Except(dbvf); worked :)

Comment: @Tiz, your join syntax isn't quite correct. You can only have one `equals` and the expression on the left of the `equals` can only reference your `p1` range variable; similarly the expression on the right can only refrence your `p2` range variable. The simplest way to solve this join issue is to use anonymous types as I did in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

something like below

```
 from dbvf in dbvfs
 from vf in vfs
 where vf.sid == dbvf.sid && vf.cid == dbvf.cid
 where dbvf.sid == null
 select new { dbvf = dbvf, vf = vf}
```

Comment: dbvf.sid is an int. So it throws an error "Warning as Error: The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?' "

Comment: @developer747 this is saying that dbvf.sid == null doesnt mean anything, is this value nullable?

Comment: nope the value is not nullable. In SQL thats how I would do it.

Comment: you cant do a linq check for null then, ie `WHERE  dbvf.sid IS NULL` isnt possible as it wont ever be valid if dbvf.sid isnt nullable

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var query =
    from v in vf
    join d in dbvf
    on new { v.sid, v.cid }
    equals new { d.sid, d.cid } into gj
    where !gj.Any()
    select v;
```

As stated earlier, your purpose is to do an "except". I've answered how to do this with left-join semantics.

```
var query =
    from v in vf
    join d in dbvf
    on new { v.sid, v.cid }
    equals new { d.sid, d.cid } into gj
    from d in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where d == null
    select v;
```

The anonymous types used here appear to be black magic to the uninitiated. However, the compiler creates the anonymous types (actually it's just one type) with exactly two properties named `sid` and `cid` as well as providing implementations for `Equals` and `GetHashCode` that `Join` will use in its implementation. My choice of `gj` for the `into` clause is because introducing the `into` causes the compiler to do a `GroupJoin` instead of a regular `Join` call.

I can add to the query to get a similar feel to your SQL sample by adding a `from d in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()` clause that reinstates the `d` range variable previously hidden by the `into` clause. Now I can add the `where d == null` clause nearly reaching parity with the original SQL.

This anonymous type introduction is something you may need to use again if you ever want to do other operations such as group by both `sid` and `cid`.